# Processing: Label text slow to update via network events

Tags: java, networking, processing

I'm working on a sketch that is receiving network events from an external program (specifically, an OpenFrameworks sketch), using the processing.net library.

Inside the draw method, I have the following code to parse the incoming data, and assign it appropriately to display a value of text in a text label:

```
void draw()
{
  // check for incoming data
  Client client = server.available();
  if (client != null) {
    // check for a full line of incoming data
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');

    if (line != null) {
      //println(line);
      int val = int(trim(line)); // extract the predicted class
      //println(val);
      if (val == 1) {
        messageText = "EVENT 1";
      } else if (val == 2) {
        messageText = "EVENT 2";
      } else if (val == 3) {
        messageText = "EVENT 3";
      }
    } 
  }

  // draw
  background(0);
  textFont(f,64);
  fill(255);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  text(messageText, width/2, height/2);

}
```

Through logging, I have verified that the data is being received properly

However, I'm experiencing a very annoying bug - the text of my messageText label is VERY slow to update...after a new event has occurred (and is shown as such through logging), the messageText will still display the value of the last event for several seconds.

Anyone have any pointers on how to speed up performance here?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Below is the full, complete sketch code:

```
import processing.net.*; // include the networking library

Server server; // will receive predictions 
String messageText;
PFont f;

void setup()
{
  fullScreen();
  //size(200,200);

  server = new Server(this, 5204); // listen on port 5204
  messageText = "NO HAND";

  f = createFont("Arial",16,true); // Arial, 16 point, anti-aliasing on
}

void draw()
{
  // check for incoming data
  Client client = server.available();
  if (client != null) {
    // check for a full line of incoming data
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');

    if (line != null) {
      //println(line);
      int val = int(trim(line)); // extract the predicted class
      //println(val);
      if (val == 1) {
        messageText = "EVENT 1";
      } else if (val == 2) {
        messageText = "EVENT 2";
      } else if (val == 3) {
        messageText = "EVENT 3";
      }
    } 
  }

  // draw
  background(0);
  textFont(f,64);
  fill(255);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  text(messageText, width/2, height/2);

}
```

**EDIT2** As Kevin pointed out below, my solution is rather hacky. I'm attempting to use the *Message Events* methods from the Networking library, rather than stuffing all my networking code inside of the `draw()` method.

So, I tried implementing the clientEvent method as such. However, I think I may be misunderstanding something...even though my original, hacky code seems to work OK now, my new code below using this delegate method doesn't seem to work at all. Basically, I have to run my sketch first, which creates a server, that my external program connects to. That program then sends out data that's received by my Processing sketch.

Here's what my full sketch looks like - anyone know where my misunderstanding may be coming from?

```
import processing.net.*; // include the networking library

Server server; // will receive predictions 
Client client;
String messageText;
int dataIn;
PFont f;

void setup() {
  fullScreen(P3D);
  frameRate(600);
  server = new Server(this, 5204); // listen on port 5204
  client = server.available();

  messageText = "NO HAND";
  textAlign(CENTER);
  fill(255);
  f = createFont("Arial",48,true); // Arial, 16 point, anti-aliasing on
  textFont(f, 120);
}

void draw() {
  // draw
  background(0);
  text(messageText, width/2, height/2);
}

// If there is information available to read
// this event will be triggered
void clientEvent(Client client) {
  String msg = client.readStringUntil('\n');
  // The value of msg will be null until the 
  // end of the String is reached
  if (msg != null) {    
      int val = int(trim(line)); // extract the predicted class
      println(val);
      if (val == 1) {
        messageText = "A";
      } else if (val == 2) {
        messageText = "B";
      } else if (val == 3) {
        messageText = "C";
      } else if (val == 4) {
        messageText = "D";
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: It's going to be pretty hard to help you without seeing a [mcve]. Where is this logging you're talking about?

Comment: @KevinWorkman It's the `println(val)` functions that are currently commented out. I updated the post with the complete sketch. Thank you!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this, other than maybe creating the `client` variable inside the `draw()` function. Shouldn't you just create that once, in the `setup()` function?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Yup, you are correct - that is a better thing to do. 
And, I realized I was a bit wrong in my original post - it looks as though the print logs are also delayed from the what the sender's values are in reality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer ended up having to do with the framerate and renderer used in the project. Since the network update code was being called in my sketch's `draw` method, the speed at which it was called was dependent on the framerate/renderer used.

After a bit of experimentation / trial-and-error, changing the sketch to use the FX2D renderer, and a framerate of 600, significantly improved performance to the degree at which I needed.

```
void setup()
{
  fullScreen(FX2D);
  frameRate(600);
  ...
}
```

**EDIT**: 
After a conversation with one of the Processing core team members, I'm considering my networking code correct and complete. Changing the renderer to FX2D significantly improved performance.

In my very specific use case, I'm running the sketch full-screen on a MacBookPro with Retina display. Bumping the framerate value high, and changing the renderer, gave me the performance I required for my quick prototype sketches.

Comment: That approach is going to eat up a ton of CPU busy-waiting for stuff that generally happens much less frequently. You'd probably be better off switching to an event-based approach instead of constantly polling.

Comment: Not entirely sure how to go about implementing an event-based approached @KevinWorkman - what would you suggest?

Comment: Check out the **Network Events** section of the reference for the networking library [here](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/net/index.html).

Comment: @KevinWorkman I somehow missed that - thank you!
Updated my question...